# speed mismatch in linux and windows

Tags: c, linux, opengl, glut

```
void myDisplay(void)  //glutDIsplayFunc(mydisplay)
{
  while(1)
  {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    x=rand()%680;
    y=rand()%680;
    sx=(x-p)/100;
    sy=(y-q)/100;
    glColor3f(0.7+sx,0.1-sy,0.6);

    for(g=0;g<120;g++)
    {
      p+=sx;
      q+=sy;
      glBegin(GL_POINTS);
      glVertex2i(p,q); 
      glEnd();
      glutSwapBuffers();
    }
  }
}
```

This code just chooses one arbitrary point on screen and do smooth translation.
 I compiled this same code in visual C++ and on linux and I noticed that the translation (from one point to another) happens fast on windows while on linux it drags slow.

why this is so?

Comment: Don't swap buffers in the middle of your drawing loop like that, that's just plain crazy. As is calling `glBegin (GL_POINTS)` for a single point. Hoist that outside of the loop instead.

Comment: this could ruin my whole translation method

Answer (score 2):

Your are using a movement vector which is totally independent of the fps. This means that it will run with a different speed on a different machine.From your description I guess that on your Linux machine, *sync to vblank* is enabled, limiting your framerate to the refresh rate of the display (typically 60Hz), while on the windows machine, it is disabled, running with a much higher frequency.

You should use a *timer* to control animations, and define your animation speeds in *sapce-units per time-unit*.

Furthermore, you should follow Andon M. Coleman's advice: The GLUT display callback is mean to draw a *single* frame. If you want an animation over many frames, use some variables to store your current state (for example, the current position and direction vector) and update them for each step. The way you currently implemented it, GLUT's event handling will by blocked for the whole duration of the animation. On windows, this might even trigger "the application is not responding" warning, when your animation takes too long.

Comment: thank you..this website realizes me how less i know about programming.i only have left last year of my college , i dont think i can ever master this programming.

Comment: No one ever masters programming. They keep learning about new things until they stop programming. That's the beauty of it!

Comment: @rishi: Don't worry about it too much. I've been using C++ for the better part of 20 years and colleagues are always shocked to learn how little of the C++ standard library I use after so many years (this is not what they would consider mastery of C++) ;) I prefer the C standard library to crazy angle brackets and colons nested everywhere. I'll never "master" C++ or Objective-C, because I cannot read it and it gets worse with every new language version :( You'll pickup on the important stuff with time.

Comment: i dont know .... i just want to be best in C , C++ and openGL , but the whole world forces me to learn JAVA because of the number of so called JAVA jobs..     Thanks for your Beautiful replies :)